# Laravel 4.2 - Migrate sessions from Redis to MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, session, redis, migration

i need to migrate all sessions stored in redis to MySQL, is there any possibility to do that?

Edit:

Working code

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
    $keys = $redis->keys('*');

    foreach ($keys as $key){
        $payload = base64_encode(unserialize($redis->get($key)));

        $id = str_replace('prefix:', '', $key);

        DB::table('sessions')->insert([
            'id'=>$id,
            'payload'=>$payload,
            'last_activity'=>$date = date('U')
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, why you still use a very very outdated version? laravel 4.2 has been outdated more than 5 years ago.

Comment: App is very huge and we are under rewriting but during doing this app's owner changed so it make us to create some temporary solutions

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't switch the sessions driver to database and discard the sessions that are currently in redis? Sessions are meant to be short-lived

Comment: Change driver to MySQL wihout migration will logout all users. For most of them it will be big trouble

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get all session data from Redis since they are stored under the session id as a key, though `Redis::keys('*')` may give you a list which you may use to load each redis entry and check if it's an actual user session.

Comment: There is, i made it, solution in question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since Laravel uses some core components of "symfony", you may use `MigratingSessionHandler` class of [symfony](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/Handler/MigratingSessionHandler.php) to migrate from one driver to another.(i didn't try this on production). It came on 2018, your version may not have that, so before you start you may need to upgrade your version to one of the recent versions.

This [document](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#migrating-between-save-handlers) provides workflow for it.

> If your application changes the way sessions are stored, use the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MigratingSessionHandler` to migrate between old and new save handlers without losing session data.

Before you start you need to create migration for database session driver. The official documentation provides the [schema](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#driver-prerequisites)

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

Comment: It can work but with newer laravel version, i made it, solution in question

Comment: @Pewulon running `keys` command for redis in production is super dangerous. Depending on your redis dbsize you may suffer from the performance. Redis is single threaded, any other command will not be executed while you are executing `keys`. https://redis.io/commands/keys -- "consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code"

Comment: This is just for single use, while app will be in maintenance mode and probably we will do this on database dump on another server